# WinForm User Controls and WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-controls

I've spent some time working on WinForm user and custom controls. However, in the back of my mind are the increasingly loud voices saying that WinForm technology is obsolete, and that WPF is the future on the desktop.

I've only looked superficially at WPF. Can anyone comment about if WinForm user controls can be used at all on WPF, and how different WinForm user controls are from WPF user controls?

Most of the controls I'm working on do some type of owner-draw as opposed to child controls being dropped onto the control. I'm just wondering how much of this code will be reusable under WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controls will be reusable (through `WindowsFormHost`, as Cody suggested).  However, I'd not bank on being able to port your code across to WPF.  The fundamental programming model is quite different (WPF relies heavily on data binding and thus benefits from very different code-behind), as is the rendering model (WPF doesn't use GDI+).  The best way to approach *most* controls in WPF is to use the built-in templating; other than custom layout panels (which isn't really "drawing"), I've found nothing so far that requires custom draw methods in controls.

It'd certainly be a waste to create a WPF application just to host your WinForms controls.  WPF may (or may not!) be "the future" but that doesn't mean you should throw away what you've got on a whim.

You say you've only looked superficially. If you think it might be worth investment, why not do an R&D project to prove how the integration might work on a small part of the system?

Comment: (Pedant) WinForms doesn't use GDI either; it uses GDI+. But yes, WPF uses an [entirely different rendering model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms742196.aspx) based on DirectX.

Comment: @Dan: Can you even still do owner draw in WPF? Seems like it's definitely oriented towards the drag-and-drop programmers.

Comment: @Jonathan: definitely not oriented toward drag & drop - with the exception of Blend for animations, the best way to carve UI in WPF is by hand-cranking markup, and it's amazing how powerful that can be if you have a good `ViewModel` class behind the scenes.  That said, the `OnRender` method on each control gets passed a `DrawingContext` that you can, if you choose, do anything you like with - though I've no idea why you would want to!

Comment: @Dan: You have _no_ _idea_ why you'd want to do owner draw? How would you do, for example, a combo box that lists colors instead of text?

Comment: In WPF?  Three lines of markup.  That's the power of it!  Ask it as a question on here and I'll post you an answer ;-)

Comment: @Jonathan: If you create a combobox and populate it with string values "Red" "Green" "Blue" etc, add this markup inside the Combobox element for a simple example: `<ComboBox.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><Border Width="100" Height="20" Background="{Binding}" /></DataTemplate></ComboBox.ItemTemplate>`

Comment: @Dan: Okay, that's cool. But what if you wanted a palette grid or something else that didn't fit within the regular list layout? I find it hard to believe you have it draw whatever you want without going to the graphics routines.

Comment: @Jon: Example for a palette grid: bind a `ListBox` to a list of colours, change the layout panel from the default `StackPanel` to a `WrapPanel` (standard layout panel that will wrap your items into multiple rows of boxes), and set up a custom template similar to what I gave above so each colour appears as a box.  Also dead simple!  Honestly: WPF gives a huge amount in terms of customising control layout and content.  I've never found need of anything more than a custom layout panel (which just positions other elements - it doesn't draw anything itself).

Comment: @Dan: Well, it's hard to believe this would efficient cover every possible display, but does sound interesting. WPF is on my list, with lots of other stuff. :-(

Comment: I'm always impressed how much you can do in pure Xaml markup.  Try downloading Kaxaml (free download - basically a Xaml scratchpad) and having a mess around.  My favourite demo (despite not having any clever UI) has always been writing an RSS reader in ~20 lines of markup :-)

Comment: @Jonathan: This is partly what I meant about having to learn an *entirely* new model for WPF than you've known for WinForms, etc. That's the primary reason I haven't made the switch; there's just no business case for taking the time to wrap my mind around it, and it will be hard to switch back and forth. There's no reason for owner-draw in WPF like we've known it, not because it's a drag-and-drop uncustomizable system, but because virtually *everything* is owner drawn. The idea is infinite customizability. I'm just not a fan of going back to hand-coding UIs like the original Windows programs.

Comment: @Cody: Yeah, different from what I've know in WinForms, ASP.NET, VB6, C++, MFC, C, QuickBASIC, assembly language, etc. It's not easy to throw everything away every time MS comes out with a new technology. But WPF is high on my list (along with ASP.NET MVC, that is). Whew!

Comment: @Jonathan: You're a better person than I am. I applaud your enthusiasm/willingness to keep up with the curve. I spent a few hours with WPF, said WTF, and went right back to WinForms/MFC. :-)

Comment: @Cody: I don't know about that. I definitely feel I'm in over my head quite frequently. BTW, I had to laugh. I just read your profile. I don't know how many times I realized I typed @Code in a comment (but corrected it). I guess my fingers have learned to type that.

Answer (score 5):

It is certainly [possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx) to use WinForms controls in a WPF application using the [`WindowsFormHost` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx). As usual, there are a few caveats. In particular, the two control types don't overlap well.

However, doing so seems that it would prevent you from taking advantage of *many* (if not nearly all) of the benefits of switching to WPF in the first place. If you have a large code base that's working for you, I'm not sure why you feel you need to migrate. There will *always* be something newer that comes along. The real battle is figuring out whether it's really *better*, at least for your particular situation.

Mandatory disclaimer: I'm far from an expert on WPF and apparently quite a bit less jaded on WinForms than many developers are. So perhaps my advice should be taken with a grain of salt, but I think it's worth considering nevertheless.

Comment: I've just read about WinForms moving more to a maintenance mode instead of Microsoft working to add new features. I figure I need to start looking at WPF when I get some time (hah!). If WinForms remains viable for many years to come, that'll be fine by me!

Comment: @Jonathan: WinForms is indeed in "maintenance mode", but I'm not really sure what that means pragmatically. MFC has been in maintenance mode since the release of VC++ 6.0. There was recently a feature pack released, but that required relatively little work on MS's part. It's still a perfectly viable platform. I'm not sure why WinForms should expect a different fate. I'm also less than compelled by the push towards every application designer inventing their own GUI. Why does every application need to draw its own menus and buttons? Can't we just let the OS do that? But that's another soapbox.

Comment: I think MFC has officially been taken out of maintenance mode. In addition to the feature pack, which has now been expanded and incorporated into the base product, there were significant language features added and there are now some very cool things in the works. Contrast that with VB6's maintenance mode. VB6 developers were pretty much dropped cold.